# Bootstrap 4 - container-fluid not working

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am new to bootstrap 4 and learning it at the moment, following a udemy tutorial. I am trying container-fluid but it's not working as expected. container-fluid is supposed to stretch the container to full width, but in my current example, it's not working as expected. Hers is my code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">


        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">  
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Vibur&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

        <title>Chicken King</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <h1 id="logo">Chicken King</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="row">

            <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img src="slide1.jpeg" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="500">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
                            <p>We had such a great time in LA!</p>
                        </div>   
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img src="slide2.jpeg" alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="500">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>Chicago</h3>
                            <p>Thank you, Chicago!</p>
                        </div>   
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img src="slide3.jpeg" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>New York</h3>
                            <p>We love the Big Apple!</p>
                        </div>   
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                </a>
            </div>


            </div>



        </div>

        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Kindly help.
Thanks.

Comment: You don't have `container-fluid` in your example.

Comment: @awran5 i had tried container-fluid also, it was not working.

Answer (score 1):

my dear friend in this code you use **container** instead of container-fluid
and container has margin. if you want stretch the container to full width you have to use **container-fluid**.

Answer (score 1):

The key is some CSS... which stretches the smaller images... ideally you should have high-res images which don't need stretching:

```
.carousel-item img {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**working snippet** below:

```css
.carousel-item img {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class=" text-center">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <h1 id="logo">Chicken King</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="">

    <div id="demo" class=" row carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ul class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="500">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
            <p>We had such a great time in LA!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="500">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Chicago</h3>
            <p>Thank you, Chicago!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/ny.jpg" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>New York</h3>
            <p>We love the Big Apple!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. it did the trick. I am quite new to CSS and web development. Got it thanks a ton mate.